# Make multiple clickacble areas in an image

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-button

I have an image, and I want to preform a different action if the user clicked on different parts of the image.

I am kinda of new hobbyist, so I don't understand everything I find on my research.
I have found a couple of solutions, but I don't quite understand how to implement any

1. [Mask the image and get the pixel color of that underneath image to know which area has been clicked](https://blahti.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/images-with-clickable-areas/)
2. [ImageMap](http://catchthecows.com/2011/08/09/ImageMap_for_Android/index.html)

PS:

- The image is in a gird like a table (if it will help)(drawing the table is NOT an option)
- I have seen a couple of other solutions, but I don't understand them, so PLEASE do not mark as duplicate. I can understand the idea behind these answers, but I can't implement them. I don't know what to do with the code provided in the answers.

I have Succeeded in making some transparent buttons and placing them on the image, but the buttons move from their relative positions when testing on different screens.
I would appreciate a help with the buttons stuff, or explaining a different way to do this.

Comment: If you have your buttons, you can try to use PercentRelativeLayout to keep your buttons in place on different screens. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html
It will work when you have exact image size and can count where to place it.

Comment: @karolinap Thanks so much, this worked for me. can you add an example and post it as an answer so I can accept it. for the public benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add layer of buttons over the image using PercentRelativeLayout
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html

First add a library:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:25.3.1'
}
```

Then in your layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_heightPercent="50%"
            app:layout_marginLeftPercent="25%"
            app:layout_marginTopPercent="25%"
            app:layout_widthPercent="50%" />
    </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This button will be in center of image.
If you want to place in somewhere else your can count your position using pixels and see it on the preview.
Buttons should have transparent background.

Answer (score 0):

A solution will be implementing an OnTouchListener() to your ImageView

The View.OnTouchListener documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html

The following code block should help you do your work:

```
    //Set onTouchListener for your imageView
    imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){ //Checking if clicked on the image

            //Get the touch position from the event
            float x = motionEvent.getX();
            float y = motionEvent.getY();

            //Divide it by image width/height to get relative ratio
            x = x / imageView.getWidth();
            y = y / imageView.getHeight();

            //Write a if-else as per your requirent
            //Here I divided the image in 4 (quandrants) and showing where it was clicked
            if(x <= 0.5 && y <= 0.5){
                Toast.makeText(StartActivity.this, "Upper Left Quadrant", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if(x < 0.5 && y > 0.5){
                Toast.makeText(StartActivity.this, "Lower Left Quadrant", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if(x > 0.5 && y <= 0.5){
                Toast.makeText(StartActivity.this, "Upper Right Quadrant", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if(x > 0.5 && y > 0.5){
                Toast.makeText(StartActivity.this, "Lower Right Quadrant", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
        return false; //We have not handled the touch event
    }
});
```

Comment: Yeh, that's a great solution, but the picture I am working with have something like 6*5 grid so it will be very hard to write the values that are corresponding to (0.5) in your example. I will be sure to upvote your answer when I gain 2 more rep.

Comment: @OmarElrefaei Can you upload your image? I guess that your grids are of variable size and that's the issue. In that case if you have successfully implemented transparent buttons for a specific screen size, use their px/dp values and the image's px/dp values to get the ratio.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I solved my problem using PercentRelativeLayout as "karolinap" advised.